# How do I search my database and return results for a partial word?

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a search query, and would like to find any rows that match a post code. In a table there is a full list of postcodes, the first half of these codes could be 'WF12', or 'DN7', etc..

I want to input a full postcode (e.g. 'dn11pq'), and retrieve rows that start with 'dn1'. I'm familiar with `LIKE` and wildcards, tried `FULL TEXT`, also `LOCATE` but to no avail.

```
 SELECT * FROM postcodeData WHERE MATCH(postcode) AGAINST ('dn11pq' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 50
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can reduce the search string.  WHERE postcode LIKE 'dn%'
Are you wanting to pass that example and get a postcode which would be ee22pq?
If not starting with, does it just need to match any character from the supplied postcode in any order?

Comment: Yes I would be passing the full postcode and I ideally want to return any row that starts with the beginning so 'wf121bh' would bring back 'wf12'

Comment: If there is no limit on the minimum number of characters that need to match, then you are only checking the first character.
`SELECT * FROM postcodeData WHERE postcode LIKE "w%" LIMIT 50 `
Essentially you can pass just the first or min character amount to the query.  You might be able to pass the whole value and use a LEFT(str, int) to do the adjustment.  It might be this "LEFT('wf121bh',1)%"  but not sure how the nested quotes work out.

Comment: From what I understand based on your example, 'WF' & 'DN' are fixed value while the the number after that is running, correct?

Comment: Somewhat they follow a syntax https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom 2 letters 1-2 number space number 2 letters